# How do I get a console project to group my appsettings.json files?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

If I start a new web api project, the appsettings files are grouped together. However, I'm creating a working project from the console app template and when I create the appsettings files manually, the do not group together. I think back in older versions, there was something I'd put in the csproj file, but I don't know how to do it in .net core and I'm not seeing anything in properties or configurations

[image]

Answer (score 174, accepted):

In the project file of your solution you can edit or add an `<ItemGroup>` element within the `<Project>` element. This worked for me:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Please Note that my console project targets [.Net Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/) and is running in Visual Studio Pro 2017 Version 15.7.5.
Also, if your Solution Explorer doesn't immediately refresh try unloading and reloading the project.

Comment: Aha! I knew it was an item group, but was missing the other parts. Thanks!

Comment: Also, fwiw, it turns out that you don't need to declare the parent separately. The first of the two `Content` nodes here is unnecessary. Just list them all in the `Include` attribute and set the `DependentUpon`.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Note to anyone reading this answer, I did require the first of the two content nodes. I suspect in your case it was elsewhere in the proj file. Otherwise, `appsettings.json` disappears entirely.

Comment: @onefootswill did you include appsettings.json in your `Include=` attribute? This works for me everywhere and it is not defined anywhere else. I've been doing it for months now.

Comment: This solution will work. Another way to do it is by creating your own customized file nesting config in the Solution Explorer. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019

Comment: Good to know but nesting config ms page states: "The feature is currently only supported for ASP.NET Core projects." and not for console projects as the OP is asking about.

Comment: I edited the second item to use globbing pattern `*` to get all files in one shot instead manually adding each file.

Comment: This method of nesting appsettings files still is currently supported. I've tested this with a .net 6 console app using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I needed to change `<Content>` for `<None>` in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac.

Answer (score 25):

[image]

You just need to click the File Nesting icon, and choose "Web"

Answer (score 9):

Using an `<ItemGroup>` with `<Content>` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044172/422877) gave me an error (in Visual Studio 2019) about "Duplicate 'Content' items included".  It turns out the .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default.  Setting the `EnableDefaultContentItems` property to `false` seems a bit rigid, so now I include the items as **`<None>`**.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Group AppSettings in Console project. Use None to prevent "Duplicate 'Content' items were included" when using (default) EnableDefaultContentItems=true -->
  <None Include="appsettings.*.json">
    <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

This does show the files grouped, but shows their properties with Build Action 'None' and 'Do Not Copy' in the Solution-explorer, so I guess that's the price for wanting them to group?

[image: Grouped appsettings.staging.json with Build Action 'None' and 'Do Not Copy']

FWIW: a file-nesting rule as suggested in [appsettings-json-not-in-hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965690/appsettings-json-not-in-hierarchy-in-vs2017-project-explore)
will not show the files as grouped/nested, but it will make it collapse if the solution-explorer collapse-button is pressed.

Comment: In VS 2019 you just need to click the 'file nesting' button at the top of Solution Explorer.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019

Comment: that doesn't work for console app projects

Comment: It doesn't work for class lib projects either :(

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in VS2022 (inspired by Yahoo Serious's answer):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.*.json" />
    <Content Include="appsettings.*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```