# appsettings.json not in hierarchy in vs2017 project explore

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a dotnet core 2.2 project working in vs2017. However something weird is going on with the appsettings. It look like this
[image]

In my others soulutions it look like this

[image]

I cant seem to find the difference between the two projects setups..

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be a console project?
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253779/how-do-i-get-a-console-project-to-group-my-appsettings-json-files/68588210#68588210

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a console project to group my appsettings.json files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253779/how-do-i-get-a-console-project-to-group-my-appsettings-json-files)

Answer (score 3):

Check your nesting settings at the top of Solution Explorer

[image: file nesting options]

More info on what the different settings mean can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019